# Redirect to Another URL depending on the Section for Right Customer Feedback

Tags: html, forms, custom-wordpress-pages

I run a small cleaning business in Australia, so I need to collect reviews/feedback from customers, but I want to avoid negative reviews, so I am trying to create a page on my website that has buttons for redirection based on what customer choose. But the problem with a page with buttons is, users can anytime come back to the page and click again on other button to leave negative review, so it will backfire.

So, I seriously need a foolproof method to use redirection method so I can collect positive reviews on GMB and negative feedback on a form so I cam improve on those points.

Is there anyway I can use any platform different from Wordpress for my feedback page? Or can create a completely different feedback page with html? (also I don’t want Google to index my feedback page so my competitors won’t see my method).

Customer feedback sample page I need help with: https://superiorcleaningandpest.com.au/customer-feedback/

Tried free form plugins and Google Sheet for this, Doesn't work the way I like it to do.

Comment: Gave you a negative review from the positive button to help you in your testing.

Comment: @Ouroborus I already knew that people can give negative review after clicking the positive button, and there will be around 20% negative reviews with this method. We are already covering that by giving various guarantees in our services which will help those who are not satisfied with the service get free of cost service. In short, trying to setup business with 100% satisfaction rate. I know, it is impossible to maintain 100% rate, but we will atleast try.

Comment: @Ouroborus now can you please remove the negative review. And I would also be pleased to know the solution. I tried Zoho survey today, but conditional redirects are not there.

Comment: The question is way to broad IMHO. Of course, there are many other possibilities than Wordpress. You could also set a cookie or a value in the browsers local storage after a feedback has been submitted. If this cookie/value is present, the user should not have the possibility to submit feedback again. Still, this is not 100% perfect as the browser storage may easily be wiped. You would also need some bot protection etc. etc. You could also send every customer an email with a link to your page, supplying an individual token to check, if the feedback was already submitted, ...